# Recursively find all GeoTIFF in current and subfolders and clip using GDAL

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, loop, bash

I have thousand of GeoTIFF file in subfolders, and I would like to crop all of them using shapefile and save in a Crop folder.

My working directory is:

```
/Data/2000/image_20000101.tif
/Data/2000/image_20000102.tif
/Data/2000/..
/Data/2001/image_20010101.tif
/Data/2001/image_20010102.tif
/Data/2001/..
/Data/2002/..
/Data/polygon.shp
/Data/Crop/
```

My script:

```
% for i in `find . -type f -name "*.tif"`; do gdalwarp --config GDALWARP_IGNORE_BAD_CUTLINE YES -srcnodata -999 -dstnodata NoData -cutline polygon.shp -crop_to_cutline $i ./Crop/crop"_"$i; done
```

Seems the looping and finding all geotiff in all subfolders is worked, but it failed to save the output.

```
ERROR 4: Attempt to create new tiff file `./Crop/crop_./2000/image_20000101.tif' failed: No such file or directory`
```

I am expecting the output inside Crop folder

```
/Data/Crop/crop_image_20000101.tif
/Data/Crop/crop_image_20000102.tif
...
```

How to solve above problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful tip with complicated shell script loops like this is to use `echo` to see what the loop would do. So:

```
$ for i in `find . -type f -name "*.tif"`; do echo $i ./Crop/crop"_"$i; done
./Data/2000/image_20000102.tif ./Crop/crop_./Data/2000/image_20000102.tif
./Data/2000/image_20000101.tif ./Crop/crop_./Data/2000/image_20000101.tif
./Data/2001/image_20010101.tif ./Crop/crop_./Data/2001/image_20010101.tif
./Data/2001/image_20010102.tif ./Crop/crop_./Data/2001/image_20010102.tif
```

that shows you what has happened - the full path to the TIF has been put at the end of the path where you want to put the output file.

Instead, you want to just put the filename, and not the whole path, on the end of that string. You can use the `basename` command, wrapped in back-ticks to replace its output into the command line:

```
$ for i in `find . -type f -name "*.tif"`; do echo $i ./Crop/crop"_"`basename $i`; done
./Data/2000/image_20000102.tif ./Crop/crop_image_20000102.tif
./Data/2000/image_20000101.tif ./Crop/crop_image_20000101.tif
./Data/2001/image_20010101.tif ./Crop/crop_image_20010101.tif
./Data/2001/image_20010102.tif ./Crop/crop_image_20010102.tif
```

Or (thanks Ian in comments) use some shell variable modification magic to get the same result but perhaps slightly quicker because the system doesn't start a new process every time (although your `gdalwarp` will swamp any gain):

```
$ for i in `find . -type f -name "*.tif"`; do echo $i ./Crop/crop"_"${i##*/}; done
./Data/2000/image_20000102.tif ./Crop/crop_image_20000102.tif
./Data/2000/image_20000101.tif ./Crop/crop_image_20000101.tif
./Data/2001/image_20010101.tif ./Crop/crop_image_20010101.tif
./Data/2001/image_20010102.tif ./Crop/crop_image_20010102.tif
```

Now imagine those lines with the `gdalwarp` command plus options instead of `echo` and I think they'd work as you want.

Another way I sometimes do things like this is to get `find` to write out the commands I want it to run, and using `printf` to write a formatted string. You can get the basename with `%f` and the full path with `%p`. So I can do:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.tif" -printf "gdalwarp -option -option ./Data/Crop/crop_%f %p\n"
gdalwarp -option -option ./Data/Crop/crop_image_20000102.tif ./Data/2000/image_20000102.tif
gdalwarp -option -option ./Data/Crop/crop_image_20000101.tif ./Data/2000/image_20000101.tif
gdalwarp -option -option ./Data/Crop/crop_image_20010101.tif ./Data/2001/image_20010101.tif
gdalwarp -option -option ./Data/Crop/crop_image_20010102.tif ./Data/2001/image_20010102.tif
```

When that looks good, send it to a file with a redirect:

```
 find . -type f -name "*.tif" -printf "gdalwarp -option -option ./Data/Crop/crop_%f %p\n" > warp.sh
```

And run that as a script using a "dot":

```
 . warp.sh
```

Comment: you can also use variable expansion instead of basename - `${Path2File##*/}`

Comment: I always get confused by variable expansions. I did look at the bash manual but glazed over. To use in the above, its `echo $i ./Crop/crop"_"${i##*/}` - this is faster because it doesn't have to run a new process for every `basename`

Comment: This script below works well
```$ for i in `find . -type f -name "*.tif"`; do echo $i ./Crop/crop"_"`basename $i`; done
```

I don't know the reason why my mac can't recognise -printf

Comment: This is `echo $i ./Crop/crop"_"${i##*/}` not worked